# help with java problem

Tags: java

this is a question for my school work i dont want the complete answer but how i should go about doing each part or help clarifying what the question is asking for

> In the following method, the call to `getCreditCardNumber()` may throw an `InvalidLengthException`,  a `NonNumericException` or  an `InvalidCardNumberException`. Modify the method to do the following:
>   a. Catch the `InvalidLengthException` and print the message “Card number must be 16 digits.”
>   b. Catch the `NonNumericException` and print the message “Card number must be numbers only.”
>   c. Pass the `InvalidCardNumberException` on to the calling method. In other words, don’t catch it, but let any calling method that uses this method know that it may throw `InvalidCardNumberException`.

```
public void getOrderInformation() 
{
    getCreditCardNumber();
}
```

Comment: The instructions are already pretty clear. Is there any part in particular that doesn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without providing exact code, per your request, you'll need to wrap your call to getCreditCardNumber() in a `try`/`catch` block using mutliple `catch` statements.

This how Java, and other languages, perform exception handling. Read this [quick tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html) and give it a shot.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the official [documentation on exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).  It's pretty short and the things you're trying to do are laid out in there.

Answer (score -1):

You mean this? o.0

```
public void getOrderInformation() throws InvalidCardNumberException
{
    try
    {
        getCreditCardNumber();
    }
    catch(InvalidLengthException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Card number must be 16 digits.");
    }
    catch(NonNumericException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Card number must be numbers only.");
    }
}
```

Comment: OP asked for help, not an answer, and surely not inaccurate answer.

Comment: If he didn't want the answer, he'd have left out the specifics :P

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer for all of these together; you can take it apart to see what I did.

```
public void getOrderInformation() throws InvalidCardNumberException
{
  try {
    getCreditCardNumber();
  } catch(InvalidLengthException ex) {
    System.err.println("Card number must be 16 digits.");
  } catch(NonNumericException ex) {
    System.err.println(“Card number must be numbers only.”);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer as there are three separate sections.  This is what would happen if you combined it all; he must dissect it to understand why each part works.